# How to embed Drupal Views in a CiviCRM Email Template?

Tags: civimail

Has anyone added a Drupal view to a CiviCRM template?

For example, we have build a CiviCRM email template with a Latest news list on the right hand side of the template. We would like to pull in the latest news links from a Drupal view that is referencing a New content type.In theory it is similar to adding a block to the right hand side of the template.

This way users creating the template do not need to manually add the links to the right hand side of the newsletter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fuzion did create a module some time ago that lets a token pull a drupal view in to a mailing. Take a look at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token

It is sometime since we had to do any work on it but hopefully it still works.

At the time it was pretty limited in what it offered but it did mean that you could eg build a 'latest news' view in Views and then have that pulled in to a bulk mail.

Comment: I currently use this with Drupal 7 and Civi 4.7.11 and it works great

Comment: Thanks @petednz and frTommy. I will test this module and see how it goes.